# What is the best place to mount a permanent Windows share in Kubuntu?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, paths, fhs

What is the best place to mount a permanent Windows share in Kubuntu?

- So that it meets the standards.
- Avoiding high usage  of CPU and network if akonadi try to index it.
- Showing better in file explorer like Dolphing.
- ...
- In short, make it more functional and useful

Thank you... And sorry for my rusty English usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/mnt` or `/media` are both fine. And it is also fine to create your own directory in `/`. Like a `/data/` or `/windowsshare/`.

Some things:

- when you do and add it to `/etc/fstab` use a `~/.smbcredentials` for storing user name and password. edit: a ~ will not work; use the whole directory.
- a windows share might have a longer waiting time then the system expects. If so, use the "noauto" in `/etc/fstab` and mount it in `/etc/rc.local`.

---

> Avoiding high usage of CPU and network if Akonadi try to index it.

and

> Showing better in file explorer like Dolphin.

are not an issue. If they are then the *mount point* itself is not the reason for it.

Comment: If I choose /media as mountroot, should I use mount point something like /media/myusername/directory ?
mounting at /media .... does not ask for a password? (I want it mounted without intervention)

Comment: Depends. Do you have more than 1 user? If so: don't and just stick it under /media/. It will not ask for a password when you put it in /etc/fstab and it does not have a password ;)